# Can we check GPU memory usage inside a CUDA kernel?

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu, gpgpu, profiler

I want to check the **free memory on the device** while executing a `CUDA` kernel. `cuMemGetInfo`(&free, &total) is a host (CPU) based command which gives free memory on the Device.

But is there any way to check free memory inside a `CUDA` kernel code during execution ?

Comment: Why do you need that? Are you allocating memory inside a kernel?

Comment: No I am not allocating memory inside a kernel. I just want to check memory consumption during execution of the kernel. Because my input data is so small, the execution is really fast hence I am unable to check usage instantaneously using commands like nvidia-smi or using normal APIs.

Comment: Well, right before running your kernel, you have access to the memory usage with `cudaMemGetInfo`, and if your kernel is not changing the amount of allocated memory, I don't really understand why that wouldn't be good enough for you.

Comment: Why don't you use CUDA Visual Profiler? It gives detailed information about your kernel execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use profiler - The `NVIDIA Visual Profiler` is a cross-platform performance profiling tool that delivers developers vital feedback for optimizing `CUDA C/C++` applications.

First introduced in 2008, Visual Profiler supports all 350 million+ CUDA capable NVIDIA GPUs shipped since 2006 on Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows.

The NVIDIA Visual Profiler is available as part of the CUDA Toolkit.

See User's Guide [Here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html)

[image]